# Printing more than one page for control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pagination

This code will only print one page but the height of the control exceeds the page height and therefore will need to be printed on a second page. I have been doing some investigation as to what will enable the control to proceed onto another page. I got as far as DocumentPaginator and fiddled with the size making it bigger and smaller than the sz variable but no difference. Any Ideas as to what controls a creation of a new page? does the size relate to pagination?

```
private void Print()
            {
                var pd = new PrintDialog();
                var document = new FixedDocument();
                var fixedPage = new FixedPage();
                var pageContent = new PageContent();
    System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = pd.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(pd.PrintTicket);
    System.Windows.Size sz = new System.Windows.Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);
                MarSheetReport mar = new MarSheetReport();
                document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = sz;
                Transform originalScale = fixedPage.LayoutTransform;
                //get selected printer capabilities


                fixedPage.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(0.2823293807641634 + 0.2498215560314061, 0.2823293807641634 + 0.2498215560314061);

                fixedPage.Width = sz.Width;
                fixedPage.Height = sz.Height;
                // Add visual, measure/arrange page.
                fixedPage.Children.Add(mar.o);
                fixedPage.Measure(sz);

                fixedPage.Arrange(new System.Windows.Rect(new System.Windows.Point(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));
                fixedPage.UpdateLayout();
                //fixedPage.LayoutTransform = originalScale;

                ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
                document.Pages.Add(pageContent);
                pd.PrintDocument(document.DocumentPaginator, "My Document");

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it i.e creating the bitmap from the visual and breaking it on multiple pages.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339416/Printing-large-WPF-UserControls